# Third column based on two other columns

Tags: r, excel

What code can I use if I want to add a third column based on two other columns.

If column 1 OR column 2 are =1, I want column 3 to say 1

In excel I know I can use

=IF((OR(F426=1,G426=1)),"1","0")

But I want to learn how to do it in R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `|`

```
df1$column3 <- with(df1, +(column1 == 1|column2 == 1))
```

---

Or with `rowSums`

```
df1$column3 <- +(rowSums(df1[c('column1', 'column2')] == 1) > 0)
```